# Gradle sync failed: Could not connect to server

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

In my android studio 3.0 i am continuously getting this error -

```
Cannot start internal HTTP server. Git integration, JavaScript debugger and LiveEdit may operate with errors. Please check your firewall settings and restart Android Studio.
```

after this my gradle sync also failed stating the error -

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not connect to server [a3ea2c7d-cc16-4af2-82a9-037277903c02 port:49555, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]. Tried addresses: [/127.0.0.1].
```

One thing to note down that this gradle sync failed when it(gradle) is connecting to gradle daemon.
i have tried all the options from stack overflow like netsh winsock reset etc.
But nothing work for me. 
Also to mention i do not use embedded JDK in AS. I have provided it my downloaded jdk8.
How to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with different network connections.

Comment: Is there any alternative instead of changing the network connection?

Comment: could not connect to server probably a network issues or connection issues. Alternately try to run android studio as 'Run as Administrator' then try.

Comment: I have tried it but problem is not solved.

Comment: Can you put a screenshot for your code, please?

-Do you use Internet permission?
-Is your URL valid? "http://DOMAIN_OR_IP.com/org

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829629/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-connect-to-server/66116408#66116408

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your machine is connected to the internet.
2. Check the link here: [Configure Android Studio - Proxy](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#proxy)
3. I personally recommend that you try disabling the proxy if it is enabled.
4. Go to Windows Firewall -> Inbound & Outbound Rules -> add **java.exe** from JDK path & **studio.exe** from Android Studio directory.

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately that doesn't solves the problem.