# gradle sync failed : Could not connect to server

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

i installed the new version of android studio . version 3.1.1 and i have new error in gradle sync:

> Could not connect to server [fc3d9512-540e-47b4-9cb0-8d3b0c134fbe port:5736, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]. Tried addresses: [/127.0.0.1].

i am using windows 10 
I think it's not related to connection because i can update sdk from sdk manager but when i want to sync gradle this message was displayed.

screenshot :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9t47.png)

Comment: Have you tried  offline sync? You can go to settings> gradule> you should see a checkbox. Unchrck and try again.

Comment: i did , but nothing changed. it was unchecked , i tried it with both checked and unchecked.

Comment: i downloaded gradle 4.6 manually and addressed the service directory path in offline mode .is it effective???

Comment: have you ever found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your firewall setting is turned off. It works for me I am using Android Studio 4.1.2 over Windows 10 and antivirus as Quick Heal, i just turned off quick heal firewall off and problem has resolved.

Answer (score -2):

If you have any antivirus installed on your pc eg. Quick Heal, so make sure you turn off your firewall setting. In my case, it works and Gradle sync was done successfully.